# Asp.Net Core Web API on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a WebAPI using Asp.Net Core 2 and trying to publish it to Azure but I cannot access the API through API Management Service. I am able to publish an older Asp.Net WebAPI with the same connection string and access it just fine, but the Asp.Net Core Web API I am not. I also notice that the Asp.Net Core API is listed as a Web App but the WebAPI is listed as a Api App. What am I doing wrong?

[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PD30.png)

Comment: What the error message you have got?

Answer (score 0):

> I also notice that the Asp.Net Core API is listed as a Web App but the WebAPI is listed as a Api App.

As I have tested, when you create WebAPI in vs you choose `Azure API App` template, so after deploying, it is listed as a API App.
[image]

When you add a new API with `API App` in APMS, it only get the WebAPI and could not access to Asp.net core WebAPI.
[image]

For more details about access the API through API Management Service, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish).

Comment: I noticed that Azure API App is .Net 4.6.1. Is there a way to add the Core framework to that template?

Comment: It seems that no way. The template is provided by the vs which rely on the vs version and the function you have installed.